# Group Policy Start Menu and IE

Tags: xml, internet-explorer

I'm having a weird problem. I'm trying to adjust what users on a computer see on the start menu and on the taskbar. I've got it mostly working. The correct taskbar items appear when users log on, and almost all of the correct items appear on the start menu. Except Internet Explorer. I used these sites to learn how to do this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-windows-10-start-screens-by-using-group-policy)

My XML page looks like this:

[image]

Is it something to do with the location, with %APPDATA%? Sometimes IE appears, but othertimes it doesn't. It always appears in the taskbar though, so I really don't know what's goinf on. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](http://ccmexec.com/2015/09/customizing-the-windows-10-start-menu-and-add-ie-shortcut-during-osd/). Just follows the steps and everything worked perfectly.